# Git - Merge a branch of one repo to a branch of another repo

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I've two repos and I wanted to merge the updates from one repo to another repo. I did the following and got 'Already up to date'

```
$ ls
dev qa

$ cd dev
$ git branch
* master
  temp-branch

$ cd ../
$ cd qa
$ git remote add dev ../dev
$ git remote update
Fetching origin
Fetching dev
From ../dev
 * [new branch]      master      -> dev/master
 * [new branch]      temp-branch -> dev/temp-branch
```

Then, I am creating a local branch on qa

```
$ git checkout -b temp-branch
Switched to a new branch 'temp-branch'
$ git merge dev/temp-branch
Already up to date.
```

The `dev/temp-branch` has an update which `qa/temp-branch` doesn't have it. Even though, the code is different why I am getting `Already up to date`?

Am I doing it wrong? If yes, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `git log --all --decorate --graph --pretty=oneline --topo-order` can help you (and us ^^) to understand the state of your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Git is being "helpful" and has setup your local `temp-branch` to track the remote `dev/temp-branch`.

Per the [documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout branch
```

> If branch is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in
>   exactly one remote (call it remote) with a matching name, treat as
>   equivalent to

```
git checkout -b branch --track remote/branch
```

---

You can view all branches and their upstream branches with the command:

```
git branch -vv
```

With sample output:

```
master       <commitId> [origin/master] Commit Message
temp-branch  <commitId> [origin/temp-branch] Commit Message
no-upstream  <commitId> Commit Message
```

---

If you want to prevent this behavior, you must use the `--no-track` flag when creating the branch.

```
git checkout -b branch --no-track
```

---

To fix your current state, I recommend you delete and recreate your local temp-branch.

1. `git checkout master` // Switch to local master
2. `git branch -d temp-branch` // Remove local branch
3. `git checkout -b temp-branch --no-track` // Recreate branch with no upstream

At this point, you should be in the state you want - but you can verity with the command `git branch -vv` listed above

Comment: @moustacheman I apologize, I wasn't clear. You need to use that option when creating the branch. I will edit my answer