# Git merging a directory from a branch of one repository to the branch of another repository

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have a two Git repositories REPO-A and REPO-B.

REPO-A have --> BRANCH-A , and BRANCH-A have following directories
DirA,
DirB,
DirC

REPO-B have ---> BRANCH-B, and
BRANCH-B have following directories
DirD,
DirE,
DirA,
DirG

I would like to Merge the DirA from BRANCH-A to BRANCH-B.
what is the best way to merge DirA ?

**Note: BRANCH-A and BRANCH-B are in different repositories.**

I am expecting some git commands to solve the problem. I tried few methods and commands but none worked.

Comment: "I tried few methods […] but non worked" – what _exactly_ have you tried?

Comment: Git only ever merges _full commits_, not directories. You might be successful using the subtree merge strategy, but I'm wondering if Git is the correct tool for your use case.

Comment: Different repositories don't matter much, you could simply fetch the branch from one repo to the other repo, then work with the local commits.

Comment: Are the branches connected in any way or do they contain unrelated history? Do the commits of branch-a, that are not in branch-b, contain changes to other files outside of dir-a?

Comment: I tried to create the another temp-DirA branch from Branch-B, and copy DirA to temp-DirA branch, just override.. then use the git merge to merge the temp-DirA into Branch-B.

Comment: Two different repositories, why not just do a cp of the files ? (for info git tracks only files, no directories)

Comment: Copy files of Dir A directly to Branch B dir A does not work. as I do not want to Override the Files. I just want to merge

Comment: Are the branches connected in any way or do they contain unrelated history? Do the commits of branch-a, that are not in branch-b, contain changes to other files outside of dir-a?          - The DirA was originally  part of Branch B only.. it was taken to Branch-A and added new features. on parallel, Branch-B continue to add new features too. Now I want to Pull the Branch-A dirA features to Branch-B dirA.

Comment: @Ash and branch-a only contains changes to this repository? Then just `git fetch` + `git merge` (or `git pull`) the remote branch into your local branch. I see two questions in this, but I don't know what question is causing you problems: 1) how to get a branch from fork into your repo 2) how to merge a single directory only, while other directories were also changed in the branch

Comment: As long as the branch names are distinct it doesn’t matter whether they come from different remote repositories.

Comment: Since Git is distributed, two repositories can share the same branches; if I clone the Linux project locally then there exists one more Linux repository. This seems to be the case given your comments here. Then I don’t see why you cannot just add the second repo as a remote in the first repo, fetch the branch, check it out, and then operate it in the first repo.

Comment: @knittl Branch-A belong to REPO-A only. To answer your questions. I am not sure what you mean how to get branch. for the second question, merging single directory only, Yes it is a independent module, there is no dependency on other directory, So I want to just merge Dir A from branch -A to Branch-B..

Comment: @Ash I'm not following. A branch does not "belong" to a repository. A branch is only a (movable) name for a commit. Commits can be freely copied (`fetch`ed or `push`ed) between repositories. If the commits labeled by `branch-a` build on top of `branch-b` and only contain changes to `dir/a`, then `fetch` + `merge`. I still have not identified the real problem here: 1) fetching commits/branches from another repository 2) merging branches (?) 3) does branch-a contain other changes in other directories? 4) something else – and it really seems like there are at least two questions in this post …

Comment: … and posts must only contain a single question. So what is _the question_ or the problem? Fetching or merging? Which part is causing you problems?

Comment: @knittl let me just simplify my question. Here I will just take 1 file as an example, this will simplify the question and understanding.

Comment: @knittl repository  REPO-A have --> BRANCH-A                                                                                                                                 
repository REPO-B have ---> BRANCH-B                                                                                        the branch-A contain the file /dirA/file.js                                                                       
the branch-B also contain the file /dirA/file.js, I would like  to merge the file.js from Branch-A to Branch-B. This is just an example, I have to merge hundreds of files like this.

Comment: @Ash you do _not_ merge "files", you merge "commits". Merge commits/branches with `git merge`. Fetching a branch from a remote repository is also a solved problem (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21353656/112968, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70691216/112968, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52653087/112968). You keep coming back and explain that branch-a and branch-b contain some file (and then mention that they also contain other files). Again, you only merge _full branches_ (based on the tree information of their commits). cont'd …

Comment: … cont'd. So it is **still** unclear if your problem is running the `git merge` command and whether that gives the expected output or if your problem/question is running the `git fetch` command to get the branch you want to merge. I have already asked 3 times which of the two problems is your question and you have always simply repeated what was already written in your question. cont'd …

Comment: … cont'd. To repeat: fetching branches from arbitrary remote repositories is a solved problem and merging branches is trivial. So what is your question? Please [edit] your question to show the commands which you have already tried (or would try/would expect to exist) and why that failed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have two different repositories they are completely separate and you can't just copy branches between them. The only thing you can do is manually copy the directories between the repositories. This will copy the files, but of course, you will lose the history.

Comment: “In general, if you have two different repositories they are completely separate and you can't just copy branches between them.” OP [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76061076/git-merging-a-directory-from-a-branch-of-one-repository-to-the-branch-of-another#comment134143236_76061076) that the histories are related (not unrelated). Git is distributed so saying that you have “two repositories” when/even though they share history is correct terminology.